# Flutter doctor, Error in the network resources section

Tags: flutter, man-in-the-middle, flutter-doctor

[!] Network resources
X A cryptographic error occurred while checking "https://pub.dev/": Handshake error in client
You may be experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, your network may be compromised, or you may have malware installed on your computer.
X A cryptographic error occurred while checking "https://storage.googleapis.com/": Handshake error in client
You may be experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, your network may be compromised, or you may have malware installed on your computer.
X A cryptographic error occurred while checking "https://maven.google.com/": Handshake error in client
You may be experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, your network may be compromised, or you may have malware installed on your computer.

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

I am experiencing an error during the installation of the new Flutter version 3.13.5 on Windows 11, which I have just installed. The error occurs when running 'flutter doctor,' and a network resources error appears as mentioned above. Please help me.

I have already tried various methods such as disabling Windows Defender.